# Not viewing the full screen in Jmeter plugins managers tab when I am trying to add new plugins

Tags: plugins, jmeter

In Jmeter When I am adding the plugins in plugins manger tab after searching the plugin it is displaying plugin related stuff but it is not viewing the "apply changes and restart button at the end "

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

As of now the Plugins Manager window has hard-coded dimensions of [1024x768](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins-manager/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jmeterplugins/repository/PluginManagerDialog.java#L52)

The options are in:

1. Change your [monitor resolution](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-your-screen-resolution-5effefe3-2eac-e306-0b5d-2073b765876b) to something higher
2. Resize the Plugins Manager window, it should adapt to your current screen dimensions and the button will become visible:

   [image]
3. It's also possible to [install plugins using JMeter Plugins Manager Command Line](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerAutomated/)

More information: [How to Install the JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)